# xamarin forms - how to get product from listview upon 'delete' button click

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

A 'delete' button is added to each item on the listview, when the user clicks the delete button it will call RemoveItemFromShoppingList() and remove the product from the shopping cart list.

I have tested calling RemoveItemFromShoppingList() and removing the first item from the shopping list. This all works fine and is the new shopping cart list is updated.

But instead of removing the first item, i want to remove the product the user clicks on. I have tried capturing the ProductId but cant get it...please advise

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingListItemSource}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.Footer>
                    <Label x:Name="Total" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="20,20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                </ListView.Footer>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductId}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Img}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Detail}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding TotalPrice, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                                
                                <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding QuantityOfProduct}"/>

                                <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SubTotal, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="Delete" Clicked="RemoveItemFromShoppingList" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

none of these are working can someone please tell me how to get the product id, when delete is clicked? thanks

```
   void RemoveItemFromShoppingList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //How can I get Id of product the user wishes to delete
        //have tried many things...
        
        
            //  var productToRemove = (Button)sender;
            // Product product = new Product();
            //var p_Id = int.Parse(productToRemove.ProductId.ToString());
            //product.ProductId = productId;
            
             //var product = ((Button)sender).BindingContext;
            //  var productId = product.id;    
            
            //Button button = (Button)sender;
            //var imt = (Grid)button.Parent;
            //var c = (Label)imt.Children[0];
            }
```

Comment: I think the Commands are recommended instead of the event handlers in these types of scenarios https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding

Answer (score 2):

use the `BindingContext` - this assumes that your `ItemsSource` is a collection of type `Product`

```
void RemoveItemFromShoppingList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = (Button)sender;
  var item = (Product)button.BindingContext;
  ...

}
```